# How to make image file from Stream that i got in REST ?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I wrote some simple REST service that get Stream from client. 
This Stream is an image that the client sent. 
Now i need to translate the Stream back to Image.

How can i do it ?

The method that i wrote:

```
    public bool AnalyzingPicture( Stream image )
    {
        if( image == null )
        {
            // Is it write to write this down ? 
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "Error" );
        }
        else
        {
            // I need here to make the image translate ... 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4.aspx

```
var image = Image.FromStream(yourStream);
```

you can than easily save it to a file:

```
image.Save("C:\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

or to a byte[]:

```
byte[] binImage;
using (var mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    binImage = mStream.ToArray();
}
```